# Count frequency of of a value in each column AND row in R or linux

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a bunch of files that look like this:

```
0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:211:209,1:209:7394:1:40 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:275:270,5:270:9669:5:152    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:380:368,11:368:12676:11:327 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:234:232,2:232:8192:2:62 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:171:167,4:167:5810:4:147    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:211:211,0:211:7393:0:0    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:120:120,0:120:4275:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:210:206,4:206:7142:4:156    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:169:163,6:163:5888:6:214  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:107:105,2:105:3689:2:78 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:46:45,1:45:1603:1:27    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:93:92,1:92:3412:1:40    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:284:281,3:281:9499:3:79 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:92:91,1:91:3252:1:29  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:177,9:177:6445:9:315  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:112:111,1:111:4105:1:41 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:128:126,2:126:4540:2:61   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:99:99,0:99:3600:0:0 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:188:185,2:185:6524:2:79 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:264:259,5:259:9394:5:180  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:210:209,1:209:7464:1:40   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:179:177,2:177:6481:2:82   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:143:140,3:140:5103:3:94 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:116:116,0:116:4172:0:0    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:147:147,0:147:5196:0:0    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:114:113,1:113:4078:1:27   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:239:237,2:237:8622:2:77   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:172:167,5:167:6139:5:192  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:257:252,5:252:8986:5:191    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:264:256,7:256:9107:7:256    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:76:76,0:76:2653:0:0   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:178:178,0:178:6273:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:143:140,3:140:5092:3:119  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:192:191,1:191:6905:1:35 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:213:210,3:210:7403:3:115    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:170:168,2:168:5947:2:80   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:204:203,1:203:7752:1:40 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:149:147,2:147:5325:2:39 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:492:486,6:486:18307:6:209 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:171:168,3:168:6048:3:113  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:69:68,1:68:2411:1:30    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:251:247,4:247:8494:4:142  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:86:86,0:86:3048:0:0 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:125:124,1:124:4466:1:36   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:86:86,0:86:3045:0:0 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:241:237,4:237:8307:4:139  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:89:89,0:89:3196:0:0 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:104:103,0:103:3798:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:157:155,2:155:5630:2:76 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:79:77,2:77:2820:2:73  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:189:185,4:185:6535:4:135    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:250:246,3:246:8679:3:83   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:374:364,9:364:13005:9:350 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:151:149,2:149:5473:2:74 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:93:93,0:93:3481:0:0   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:202:200,2:200:7369:2:82 0/0:164:164,0:164:5902:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:127:125,2:125:4279:2:79   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:185:184,1:184:6563:1:40 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:93:92,1:92:3396:1:37    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:91:91,0:91:3367:0:0   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:119:116,3:116:4212:3:116    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:173:171,2:171:6295:2:74   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:199:197,2:197:7156:2:50 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:128:124,3:124:4488:3:108  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:99:96,3:96:3514:3:114 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:178:177,0:177:6244:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:203:203,0:203:7094:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:149:145,4:145:5284:4:148    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:57:57,0:57:2014:0:0 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:209:207,2:207:7422:2:51   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:132:131,1:131:4533:1:29   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:156:155,1:155:5756:1:41   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:146:144,2:144:5269:2:55   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:283:280,3:280:9926:3:106    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:278:273,5:273:9615:5:199  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:148:145,3:145:5187:3:102    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:98:96,2:96:3520:2:40    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:161:161,0:161:5991:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:294:289,4:289:10251:4:148   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:89:84,5:84:2999:5:170 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:256:252,4:252:8725:4:118  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:131:130,1:130:4710:1:26   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:248:246,2:246:8736:2:68   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:150:148,1:148:5295:1:27   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:161:160,1:160:5862:1:39 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:126:125,1:125:4304:1:38   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:82:81,1:81:2959:1:40  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:180:179,0:179:6457:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:165:165,0:165:5836:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:60:59,1:59:2160:1:40  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:218:213,4:213:7717:4:141    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:197:193,4:193:6975:4:113    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:220:219,1:219:7697:1:39   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:161:160,1:160:5680:1:24 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:276:275,1:275:9672:1:40 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:117:115,2:115:4210:2:78 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:227:226,1:226:8173:1:37   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:214:212,2:212:7590:2:49 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:212:208,4:208:7450:4:156  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:270:268,2:268:9500:2:55 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:176:174,2:174:6232:2:78 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:213:213,0:213:7408:0:0          
0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:209:204,5:204:7581:5:165    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:290:283,6:283:10667:6:238   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:420:408,10:408:15061:10:362 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:243:234,9:234:8739:9:338    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:173:163,8:163:6123:8:282    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:230:219,9:219:8198:9:351  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:118:115,2:115:4291:2:80 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:218:213,3:213:7952:3:103    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:170:161,7:161:6040:7:283  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:101:99,2:99:3700:2:72   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:50:49,1:49:1818:1:40    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:89:86,2:86:3283:2:79    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:303:292,9:292:10594:9:331   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:100:98,2:98:3695:2:81 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:196:188,8:188:7194:8:318  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:104:101,2:101:3820:2:79 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:125:120,4:120:4505:4:161  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:87:86,1:86:3280:1:41    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:187:183,4:183:6728:4:149    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:276:267,6:267:10068:6:225 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:202:200,1:200:7454:1:41   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:185:183,2:183:6915:2:81   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:148:144,4:144:5477:4:162    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:119:113,5:113:4221:5:195  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:160:154,5:154:5765:5:195  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:106:105,1:105:3992:1:30   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:236:231,5:231:8803:5:198  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:168:165,3:165:6369:3:118  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:272:267,5:267:10131:5:174   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:279:269,9:269:10163:9:322   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:71:69,2:69:2522:2:80  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:176:174,2:174:6622:2:82 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:135:130,3:130:4881:3:121  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:196:190,3:190:7246:3:85 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:226:220,3:220:8009:3:120    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:165:157,5:157:5839:5:193  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:205:191,13:191:7523:13:521  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:138:131,6:131:4989:6:231    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:503:494,7:494:19343:7:280 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:166:160,4:160:6007:4:158  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:71:71,0:71:2650:0:0 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:267:259,6:259:9522:6:223  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:85:84,1:84:3210:1:41    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:124:119,4:119:4429:4:160  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:86:85,1:85:3057:1:41    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:239:229,10:229:8520:10:375    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:83:79,2:79:2952:2:77    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:102:101,1:101:3918:1:41 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:154:147,4:147:5673:4:162    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:77:71,6:71:2756:6:232 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:201:197,4:197:7319:4:157    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:257:243,13:243:9045:13:494    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:395:381,12:381:14581:12:457   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:149:139,8:139:5221:8:321    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:94:94,0:94:3678:0:0   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:206:202,2:202:7876:2:82 0/0:166:162,4:162:6195:4:156    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:130:124,3:124:4611:3:121  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:192:181,10:181:6798:10:390  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:92:90,2:90:3479:2:56    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:94:91,2:91:3506:2:61  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:122:120,0:120:4632:0:0  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:190:187,3:187:7237:3:123  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:205:200,3:200:7714:3:115    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:123:119,3:119:4449:3:119  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:99:95,4:95:3642:4:157 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:179,8:179:6732:8:317    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:206:200,6:200:7409:6:208    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:145:142,3:142:5450:3:120    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:58:54,3:54:2042:3:123   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:219:216,3:216:8106:3:117  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:136:133,2:133:4994:2:72   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:160:155,3:155:5859:3:123  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:150:149,1:149:5680:1:41   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:301:294,5:294:10911:5:186   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:281:274,6:274:10163:6:237 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:148:139,8:139:5109:8:316    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:100:95,3:95:3539:3:108  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:156:152,2:152:5819:2:82 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:328:316,9:316:11851:9:332   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:79:76,2:76:2899:2:72  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:279:271,4:271:10063:4:152 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:132:131,1:131:4879:1:40   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:263:256,5:256:9603:5:200  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:156:151,4:151:5718:4:158  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:166:160,6:160:6085:6:206    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:125:124,1:124:4598:1:41   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:83:80,3:80:3018:3:111 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:179:176,1:176:6760:1:40 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:163:159,3:159:5920:3:117    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:58:57,1:57:2151:1:39  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:223:220,2:220:8249:2:64 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:202:194,7:194:7337:7:278    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:233:226,6:226:8502:6:222  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:155:149,6:149:5460:6:229    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:301:298,3:298:11221:3:112   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:121:117,3:117:4474:3:118    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:246:239,5:239:9069:5:198  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:208:203,4:203:7672:4:124    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:217:206,8:206:7743:8:323  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:278:272,3:272:10136:3:80    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:164:162,1:162:6019:1:41 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:220:210,10:210:7965:10:379          
0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:204:185,11:185:6936:11:429  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:290:273,7:273:10469:7:274   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:419:394,10:394:14582:10:352 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:243:231,9:231:8656:9:330    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:173:160,5:160:5946:5:189    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:230:213,10:213:7981:10:395    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:117:103,4:103:3769:4:163    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:218:199,8:199:7471:8:296    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:166:161,3:161:6162:3:115  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:97:89,4:89:3318:4:141   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:50:47,2:47:1749:2:67    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:89:80,6:80:3132:6:205   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:302:286,4:286:10388:4:143   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:100:94,5:94:3641:5:195    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:196:186,5:186:7194:5:197  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:102:94,5:94:3629:5:186  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:125:118,3:118:4509:3:120  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:87:84,3:84:3214:3:119   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:186:180,6:180:6764:6:211    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:273:262,5:262:9937:5:189  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:200:193,5:193:7242:5:202  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:184:171,7:171:6570:7:271  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:148:140,3:140:5389:3:119    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:119:112,3:112:4197:3:103  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:160:150,10:150:5595:10:361    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:106:101,3:101:3900:3:111  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:235:224,7:224:8609:7:273  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:166:160,2:160:6118:2:81   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:272:243,14:243:9285:14:506  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:279:255,6:255:9636:6:231    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:70:67,2:67:2503:2:77  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:176:171,4:171:6484:4:139    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:134:118,10:118:4501:10:359    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:196:186,4:186:7135:4:154    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:226:216,5:216:7949:5:191    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:165:152,4:152:5785:4:130  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:203:186,7:186:7371:7:273    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:138:128,3:128:4941:3:109    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:498:475,12:475:18785:12:481   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:164:154,5:154:5840:5:203  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:71:63,7:63:2386:7:236   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:267:246,13:246:9251:13:506    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:82:77,5:77:2900:5:187   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:124:109,8:109:4104:8:304  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:84:81,1:81:2982:1:41    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:238:227,4:227:8535:4:134  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:83:83,0:83:3202:0:0 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:102:97,4:97:3723:4:143  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:154:148,4:148:5730:4:156    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:77:73,3:73:2826:3:120 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:201:186,9:186:6790:9:333    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:257:251,2:251:9374:2:66   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:394:378,6:378:14429:6:233 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:149:135,7:135:5144:7:269    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:94:90,2:90:3514:2:81  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:206:192,10:192:7513:10:396  0/0:166:159,4:159:6133:4:144    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:129:120,4:120:4466:4:139  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:191:186,4:186:7067:4:161    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:92:85,4:85:3282:4:164   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:93:80,5:80:3167:5:184 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:121:117,2:117:4433:2:44 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:173,8:173:6766:8:300  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:205:191,6:191:7398:6:244    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:122:113,6:113:4245:6:229  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:99:96,0:96:3692:0:0   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:170,8:170:6453:8:296    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:206:192,4:192:7161:4:147    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:145:135,7:135:5138:7:273    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:58:55,2:55:2094:2:78    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:216:205,6:205:7754:6:220  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:136:126,9:126:4707:9:307  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:160:150,6:150:5828:6:172  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:150:139,9:139:5320:9:348  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:301:275,15:275:10428:15:538 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:281:269,9:269:10045:9:361 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:147:135,5:135:5000:5:171    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:98:93,3:93:3543:3:109   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:155:151,2:151:5836:2:75 0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:328:311,8:311:11736:8:300   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:78:71,2:71:2640:2:81  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:279:258,14:258:9564:14:549    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:127:118,7:118:4401:7:279  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:264:249,11:249:9500:11:411    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:156:143,8:143:5426:8:274  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:165:151,9:151:5764:9:353    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:124:118,4:118:4391:4:123  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:83:82,1:82:3082:1:41  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:174:166,8:166:6457:8:290    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:161:155,5:155:5759:5:178    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:58:52,1:52:1998:1:38  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:222:204,12:204:7672:12:447  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:202:191,4:191:7285:4:149    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:231:218,7:218:8277:7:265  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:153:142,8:142:5197:8:305    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:301:285,8:285:10958:8:296   0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:121:117,3:117:4479:3:123    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:246:222,12:222:8464:12:463    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:206:188,7:188:7096:7:273    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:215:195,13:195:7406:13:464    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:278:256,13:256:9662:13:506  0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:159:153,4:153:5690:4:147    0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:219:203,13:203:7765:13:490
```

And what I want to do is count the number of occurances of 0/ in every row in every column and output it to a new data frame like so:

```
46  50  50  50  50  48  54  46  48  50  42  42  46  52  48  46  48  42  50  44  44  44  50  52  48  48  48  48  46  46  48  46  48  54  50  48  46  46  44  48  42  52  46  48  46  48  46  50  46  44  46  44  44  46  40  50  2   52  46  54  48  50  44  46  52  52  50  46  42  50  48  52  44  48  46  48  46  50  54  42  54  52  44  44  48  50  52  44  46  50  56  50  58  44  50  42  46  52  50  48  46  46  50
46  50  50  50  50  48  54  46  48  50  42  42  46  52  48  46  48  42  50  44  44  44  50  52  48  48  48  48  46  46  48  46  48  54  50  48  44  46  44  48  42  52  46  48  46  48  46  50  46  42  46  44  44  46  40  50  2   52  46  54  48  50  44  46  52  52  50  46  42  50  48  52  44  48  46  48  46  50  54  42  56  52  44  44  48  50  52  44  46  50  56  50  58  44  50  42  46  52  50  48  46  46  50
46  50  50  50  50  48  54  46  48  50  42  40  46  52  48  46  48  42  50  44  44  44  50  52  46  48  48  48  46  46  48  46  46  54  50  48  46  46  44  48  40  52  44  46  46  48  46  50  46  44  46  44  44  46  40  50  2   52  46  54  46  50  44  46  52  52  50  46  42  50  48  50  44  46  46  48  46  50  54  42  56  52  44  44  48  48  52  44  46  50  56  50  58  44  50  42  46  52  50  46  46  46  48
```

Preferably with R or linux, but I am able to use perl and python as well. I understand that the last 0 in the sequence won't have the / and won't get counted, but I don't see a way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count `/0` (0 preceded by "/") or `^0` (0 at the start of the word) instead. Here is a base R approach.

```
data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) lengths(gregexpr("(^|/)0", x))))
```

Output

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39 V40
1 24 26 26 26 25 25 28 24 24  26  22  22  24  27  24  24  25  22  26  23  23  23  26  27  25  25  25  24  24  23  25  24  24  28  26  25  24  24  23  25
2 24 25 25 25 25 24 27 24 24  25  22  21  23  26  24  23  24  22  26  22  23  23  25  26  24  25  24  24  24  23  24  24  24  28  26  24  22  23  23  24
3 23 25 26 25 25 24 27 23 25  25  21  20  24  26  24  23  24  21  25  23  23  22  26  27  23  24  24  25  23  24  25  24  23  28  26  25  23  24  23  24
  V41 V42 V43 V44 V45 V46 V47 V48 V49 V50 V51 V52 V53 V54 V55 V56 V57 V58 V59 V60 V61 V62 V63 V64 V65 V66 V67 V68 V69 V70 V71 V72 V73 V74 V75 V76 V77 V78
1  22  27  24  25  24  25  24  26  24  22  24  23  23  24  21  26   2  27  24  28  25  26  23  24  26  26  26  24  21  26  25  27  23  25  24  25  24  26
2  22  26  24  24  24  24  23  26  23  21  23  22  22  23  21  26   2  27  23  28  25  26  23  24  26  26  25  23  21  25  25  27  23  25  24  25  23  25
3  20  26  22  23  24  25  24  25  23  22  23  23  23  23  21  25   2  26  24  27  23  26  22  23  26  27  25  24  21  25  24  25  23  23  23  24  24  25
  V79 V80 V81 V82 V83 V84 V85 V86 V87 V88 V89 V90 V91 V92 V93 V94 V95 V96 V97 V98 V99 V100 V101 V102 V103
1  28  22  27  27  23  23  25  26  27  23  24  26  28  26  30  23  26  22  24  27  26   25   24   24   26
2  28  21  28  27  23  23  24  25  27  22  24  25  28  26  29  22  25  22  24  26  26   24   24   24   25
3  28  21  28  26  22  22  24  24  27  23  23  25  29  25  30  22  25  21  24  26  25   23   23   23   24
```

Data

```
structure(list(V1 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:211:209,1:209:7394:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:209:204,5:204:7581:5:165", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:204:185,11:185:6936:11:429"
), V2 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:275:270,5:270:9669:5:152", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:290:283,6:283:10667:6:238", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:290:273,7:273:10469:7:274"
), V3 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:380:368,11:368:12676:11:327", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:420:408,10:408:15061:10:362", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:419:394,10:394:14582:10:352"
), V4 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:234:232,2:232:8192:2:62", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:243:234,9:234:8739:9:338", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:243:231,9:231:8656:9:330"
), V5 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:171:167,4:167:5810:4:147", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:173:163,8:163:6123:8:282", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:173:160,5:160:5946:5:189"
), V6 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:211:211,0:211:7393:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:230:219,9:219:8198:9:351", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:230:213,10:213:7981:10:395"
), V7 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:120:120,0:120:4275:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:118:115,2:115:4291:2:80", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:117:103,4:103:3769:4:163"
), V8 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:210:206,4:206:7142:4:156", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:218:213,3:213:7952:3:103", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:218:199,8:199:7471:8:296"
), V9 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:169:163,6:163:5888:6:214", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:170:161,7:161:6040:7:283", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:166:161,3:161:6162:3:115"
), V10 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:107:105,2:105:3689:2:78", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:101:99,2:99:3700:2:72", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:97:89,4:89:3318:4:141"
), V11 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:46:45,1:45:1603:1:27", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:50:49,1:49:1818:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:50:47,2:47:1749:2:67"
), V12 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:93:92,1:92:3412:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:89:86,2:86:3283:2:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:89:80,6:80:3132:6:205"
), V13 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:284:281,3:281:9499:3:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:303:292,9:292:10594:9:331", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:302:286,4:286:10388:4:143"
), V14 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:92:91,1:91:3252:1:29", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:100:98,2:98:3695:2:81", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:100:94,5:94:3641:5:195"
), V15 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:177,9:177:6445:9:315", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:196:188,8:188:7194:8:318", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:196:186,5:186:7194:5:197"
), V16 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:112:111,1:111:4105:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:104:101,2:101:3820:2:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:102:94,5:94:3629:5:186"
), V17 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:128:126,2:126:4540:2:61", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:125:120,4:120:4505:4:161", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:125:118,3:118:4509:3:120"
), V18 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:99:99,0:99:3600:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:87:86,1:86:3280:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:87:84,3:84:3214:3:119"
), V19 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:188:185,2:185:6524:2:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:187:183,4:183:6728:4:149", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:186:180,6:180:6764:6:211"
), V20 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:264:259,5:259:9394:5:180", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:276:267,6:267:10068:6:225", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:273:262,5:262:9937:5:189"
), V21 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:210:209,1:209:7464:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:202:200,1:200:7454:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:200:193,5:193:7242:5:202"
), V22 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:179:177,2:177:6481:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:185:183,2:183:6915:2:81", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:184:171,7:171:6570:7:271"
), V23 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:143:140,3:140:5103:3:94", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:148:144,4:144:5477:4:162", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:148:140,3:140:5389:3:119"
), V24 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:116:116,0:116:4172:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:119:113,5:113:4221:5:195", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:119:112,3:112:4197:3:103"
), V25 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:147:147,0:147:5196:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:160:154,5:154:5765:5:195", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:160:150,10:150:5595:10:361"
), V26 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:114:113,1:113:4078:1:27", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:106:105,1:105:3992:1:30", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:106:101,3:101:3900:3:111"
), V27 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:239:237,2:237:8622:2:77", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:236:231,5:231:8803:5:198", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:235:224,7:224:8609:7:273"
), V28 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:172:167,5:167:6139:5:192", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:168:165,3:165:6369:3:118", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:166:160,2:160:6118:2:81"
), V29 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:257:252,5:252:8986:5:191", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:272:267,5:267:10131:5:174", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:272:243,14:243:9285:14:506"
), V30 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:264:256,7:256:9107:7:256", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:279:269,9:269:10163:9:322", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:279:255,6:255:9636:6:231"
), V31 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:76:76,0:76:2653:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:71:69,2:69:2522:2:80", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:70:67,2:67:2503:2:77"
), V32 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:178:178,0:178:6273:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:176:174,2:174:6622:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:176:171,4:171:6484:4:139"
), V33 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:143:140,3:140:5092:3:119", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:135:130,3:130:4881:3:121", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:134:118,10:118:4501:10:359"
), V34 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:192:191,1:191:6905:1:35", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:196:190,3:190:7246:3:85", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:196:186,4:186:7135:4:154"
), V35 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:213:210,3:210:7403:3:115", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:226:220,3:220:8009:3:120", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:226:216,5:216:7949:5:191"
), V36 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:170:168,2:168:5947:2:80", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:165:157,5:157:5839:5:193", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:165:152,4:152:5785:4:130"
), V37 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:204:203,1:203:7752:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:205:191,13:191:7523:13:521", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:203:186,7:186:7371:7:273"
), V38 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:149:147,2:147:5325:2:39", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:138:131,6:131:4989:6:231", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:138:128,3:128:4941:3:109"
), V39 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:492:486,6:486:18307:6:209", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:503:494,7:494:19343:7:280", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:498:475,12:475:18785:12:481"
), V40 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:171:168,3:168:6048:3:113", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:166:160,4:160:6007:4:158", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:164:154,5:154:5840:5:203"
), V41 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:69:68,1:68:2411:1:30", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:71:71,0:71:2650:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:71:63,7:63:2386:7:236"
), V42 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:251:247,4:247:8494:4:142", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:267:259,6:259:9522:6:223", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:267:246,13:246:9251:13:506"
), V43 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:86:86,0:86:3048:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:85:84,1:84:3210:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:82:77,5:77:2900:5:187"
), V44 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:125:124,1:124:4466:1:36", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:124:119,4:119:4429:4:160", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:124:109,8:109:4104:8:304"
), V45 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:86:86,0:86:3045:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:86:85,1:85:3057:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:84:81,1:81:2982:1:41"
), V46 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:241:237,4:237:8307:4:139", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:239:229,10:229:8520:10:375", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:238:227,4:227:8535:4:134"
), V47 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:89:89,0:89:3196:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:83:79,2:79:2952:2:77", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:83:83,0:83:3202:0:0"
), V48 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:104:103,0:103:3798:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:102:101,1:101:3918:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:102:97,4:97:3723:4:143"
), V49 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:157:155,2:155:5630:2:76", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:154:147,4:147:5673:4:162", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:154:148,4:148:5730:4:156"
), V50 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:79:77,2:77:2820:2:73", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:77:71,6:71:2756:6:232", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:77:73,3:73:2826:3:120"
), V51 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:189:185,4:185:6535:4:135", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:201:197,4:197:7319:4:157", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:201:186,9:186:6790:9:333"
), V52 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:250:246,3:246:8679:3:83", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:257:243,13:243:9045:13:494", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:257:251,2:251:9374:2:66"
), V53 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:374:364,9:364:13005:9:350", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:395:381,12:381:14581:12:457", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:394:378,6:378:14429:6:233"
), V54 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:151:149,2:149:5473:2:74", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:149:139,8:139:5221:8:321", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:149:135,7:135:5144:7:269"
), V55 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:93:93,0:93:3481:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:94:94,0:94:3678:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:94:90,2:90:3514:2:81"
), V56 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:202:200,2:200:7369:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:206:202,2:202:7876:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:206:192,10:192:7513:10:396"
), V57 = c("0/0:164:164,0:164:5902:0:0", "0/0:166:162,4:162:6195:4:156", 
"0/0:166:159,4:159:6133:4:144"), V58 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:127:125,2:125:4279:2:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:130:124,3:124:4611:3:121", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:129:120,4:120:4466:4:139"
), V59 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:185:184,1:184:6563:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:192:181,10:181:6798:10:390", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:191:186,4:186:7067:4:161"
), V60 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:93:92,1:92:3396:1:37", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:92:90,2:90:3479:2:56", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:92:85,4:85:3282:4:164"
), V61 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:91:91,0:91:3367:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:94:91,2:91:3506:2:61", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:93:80,5:80:3167:5:184"
), V62 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:119:116,3:116:4212:3:116", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:122:120,0:120:4632:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:121:117,2:117:4433:2:44"
), V63 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:173:171,2:171:6295:2:74", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:190:187,3:187:7237:3:123", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:173,8:173:6766:8:300"
), V64 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:199:197,2:197:7156:2:50", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:205:200,3:200:7714:3:115", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:205:191,6:191:7398:6:244"
), V65 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:128:124,3:124:4488:3:108", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:123:119,3:119:4449:3:119", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:122:113,6:113:4245:6:229"
), V66 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:99:96,3:96:3514:3:114", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:99:95,4:95:3642:4:157", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:99:96,0:96:3692:0:0"
), V67 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:178:177,0:177:6244:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:179,8:179:6732:8:317", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:170,8:170:6453:8:296"
), V68 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:203:203,0:203:7094:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:206:200,6:200:7409:6:208", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:206:192,4:192:7161:4:147"
), V69 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:149:145,4:145:5284:4:148", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:145:142,3:142:5450:3:120", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:145:135,7:135:5138:7:273"
), V70 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:57:57,0:57:2014:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:58:54,3:54:2042:3:123", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:58:55,2:55:2094:2:78"
), V71 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:209:207,2:207:7422:2:51", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:219:216,3:216:8106:3:117", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:216:205,6:205:7754:6:220"
), V72 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:132:131,1:131:4533:1:29", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:136:133,2:133:4994:2:72", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:136:126,9:126:4707:9:307"
), V73 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:156:155,1:155:5756:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:160:155,3:155:5859:3:123", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:160:150,6:150:5828:6:172"
), V74 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:146:144,2:144:5269:2:55", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:150:149,1:149:5680:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:150:139,9:139:5320:9:348"
), V75 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:283:280,3:280:9926:3:106", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:301:294,5:294:10911:5:186", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:301:275,15:275:10428:15:538"
), V76 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:278:273,5:273:9615:5:199", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:281:274,6:274:10163:6:237", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:281:269,9:269:10045:9:361"
), V77 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:148:145,3:145:5187:3:102", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:148:139,8:139:5109:8:316", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:147:135,5:135:5000:5:171"
), V78 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:98:96,2:96:3520:2:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:100:95,3:95:3539:3:108", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:98:93,3:93:3543:3:109"
), V79 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:161:161,0:161:5991:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:156:152,2:152:5819:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:155:151,2:151:5836:2:75"
), V80 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:294:289,4:289:10251:4:148", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:328:316,9:316:11851:9:332", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:328:311,8:311:11736:8:300"
), V81 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:89:84,5:84:2999:5:170", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:79:76,2:76:2899:2:72", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:78:71,2:71:2640:2:81"
), V82 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:256:252,4:252:8725:4:118", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:279:271,4:271:10063:4:152", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:279:258,14:258:9564:14:549"
), V83 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:131:130,1:130:4710:1:26", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:132:131,1:131:4879:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:127:118,7:118:4401:7:279"
), V84 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:248:246,2:246:8736:2:68", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:263:256,5:256:9603:5:200", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:264:249,11:249:9500:11:411"
), V85 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:150:148,1:148:5295:1:27", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:156:151,4:151:5718:4:158", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:156:143,8:143:5426:8:274"
), V86 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:161:160,1:160:5862:1:39", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:166:160,6:160:6085:6:206", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:165:151,9:151:5764:9:353"
), V87 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:126:125,1:125:4304:1:38", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:125:124,1:124:4598:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:124:118,4:118:4391:4:123"
), V88 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:82:81,1:81:2959:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:83:80,3:80:3018:3:111", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:83:82,1:82:3082:1:41"
), V89 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:180:179,0:179:6457:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:179:176,1:176:6760:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:174:166,8:166:6457:8:290"
), V90 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:165:165,0:165:5836:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:163:159,3:159:5920:3:117", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:161:155,5:155:5759:5:178"
), V91 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:60:59,1:59:2160:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:58:57,1:57:2151:1:39", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:58:52,1:52:1998:1:38"
), V92 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:218:213,4:213:7717:4:141", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:223:220,2:220:8249:2:64", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:222:204,12:204:7672:12:447"
), V93 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:197:193,4:193:6975:4:113", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:202:194,7:194:7337:7:278", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:202:191,4:191:7285:4:149"
), V94 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:220:219,1:219:7697:1:39", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:233:226,6:226:8502:6:222", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:231:218,7:218:8277:7:265"
), V95 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:161:160,1:160:5680:1:24", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:155:149,6:149:5460:6:229", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:153:142,8:142:5197:8:305"
), V96 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:276:275,1:275:9672:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:301:298,3:298:11221:3:112", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:301:285,8:285:10958:8:296"
), V97 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:117:115,2:115:4210:2:78", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:121:117,3:117:4474:3:118", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:121:117,3:117:4479:3:123"
), V98 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:227:226,1:226:8173:1:37", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:246:239,5:239:9069:5:198", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:246:222,12:222:8464:12:463"
), V99 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:214:212,2:212:7590:2:49", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:208:203,4:203:7672:4:124", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:206:188,7:188:7096:7:273"
), V100 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:212:208,4:208:7450:4:156", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:217:206,8:206:7743:8:323", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:215:195,13:195:7406:13:464"
), V101 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:270:268,2:268:9500:2:55", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:278:272,3:272:10136:3:80", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:278:256,13:256:9662:13:506"
), V102 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:176:174,2:174:6232:2:78", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:164:162,1:162:6019:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:159:153,4:153:5690:4:147"
), V103 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:213:213,0:213:7408:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:220:210,10:210:7965:10:379", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:219:203,13:203:7765:13:490"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_count` with `mutate`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_count(., "(^|/)0")))
```

-output

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36
1 24 26 26 26 25 25 28 24 24  26  22  22  24  27  24  24  25  22  26  23  23  23  26  27  25  25  25  24  24  23  25  24  24  28  26  25
2 24 25 25 25 25 24 27 24 24  25  22  21  23  26  24  23  24  22  26  22  23  23  25  26  24  25  24  24  24  23  24  24  24  28  26  24
3 23 25 26 25 25 24 27 23 25  25  21  20  24  26  24  23  24  21  25  23  23  22  26  27  23  24  24  25  23  24  25  24  23  28  26  25
  V37 V38 V39 V40 V41 V42 V43 V44 V45 V46 V47 V48 V49 V50 V51 V52 V53 V54 V55 V56 V57 V58 V59 V60 V61 V62 V63 V64 V65 V66 V67 V68 V69
1  24  24  23  25  22  27  24  25  24  25  24  26  24  22  24  23  23  24  21  26   2  27  24  28  25  26  23  24  26  26  26  24  21
2  22  23  23  24  22  26  24  24  24  24  23  26  23  21  23  22  22  23  21  26   2  27  23  28  25  26  23  24  26  26  25  23  21
3  23  24  23  24  20  26  22  23  24  25  24  25  23  22  23  23  23  23  21  25   2  26  24  27  23  26  22  23  26  27  25  24  21
  V70 V71 V72 V73 V74 V75 V76 V77 V78 V79 V80 V81 V82 V83 V84 V85 V86 V87 V88 V89 V90 V91 V92 V93 V94 V95 V96 V97 V98 V99 V100 V101 V102
1  26  25  27  23  25  24  25  24  26  28  22  27  27  23  23  25  26  27  23  24  26  28  26  30  23  26  22  24  27  26   25   24   24
2  25  25  27  23  25  24  25  23  25  28  21  28  27  23  23  24  25  27  22  24  25  28  26  29  22  25  22  24  26  26   24   24   24
3  25  24  25  23  23  23  24  24  25  28  21  28  26  22  22  24  24  27  23  23  25  29  25  30  22  25  21  24  26  25   23   23   23
  V103
1   26
2   25
3   24
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(V1 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:211:209,1:209:7394:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:209:204,5:204:7581:5:165", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:204:185,11:185:6936:11:429"
), V2 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:275:270,5:270:9669:5:152", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:290:283,6:283:10667:6:238", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:290:273,7:273:10469:7:274"
), V3 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:380:368,11:368:12676:11:327", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:420:408,10:408:15061:10:362", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:419:394,10:394:14582:10:352"
), V4 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:234:232,2:232:8192:2:62", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:243:234,9:234:8739:9:338", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:243:231,9:231:8656:9:330"
), V5 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:171:167,4:167:5810:4:147", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:173:163,8:163:6123:8:282", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:173:160,5:160:5946:5:189"
), V6 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:211:211,0:211:7393:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:230:219,9:219:8198:9:351", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:230:213,10:213:7981:10:395"
), V7 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:120:120,0:120:4275:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:118:115,2:115:4291:2:80", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:117:103,4:103:3769:4:163"
), V8 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:210:206,4:206:7142:4:156", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:218:213,3:213:7952:3:103", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:218:199,8:199:7471:8:296"
), V9 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:169:163,6:163:5888:6:214", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:170:161,7:161:6040:7:283", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:166:161,3:161:6162:3:115"
), V10 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:107:105,2:105:3689:2:78", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:101:99,2:99:3700:2:72", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:97:89,4:89:3318:4:141"
), V11 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:46:45,1:45:1603:1:27", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:50:49,1:49:1818:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:50:47,2:47:1749:2:67"
), V12 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:93:92,1:92:3412:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:89:86,2:86:3283:2:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:89:80,6:80:3132:6:205"
), V13 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:284:281,3:281:9499:3:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:303:292,9:292:10594:9:331", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:302:286,4:286:10388:4:143"
), V14 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:92:91,1:91:3252:1:29", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:100:98,2:98:3695:2:81", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:100:94,5:94:3641:5:195"
), V15 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:177,9:177:6445:9:315", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:196:188,8:188:7194:8:318", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:196:186,5:186:7194:5:197"
), V16 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:112:111,1:111:4105:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:104:101,2:101:3820:2:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:102:94,5:94:3629:5:186"
), V17 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:128:126,2:126:4540:2:61", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:125:120,4:120:4505:4:161", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:125:118,3:118:4509:3:120"
), V18 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:99:99,0:99:3600:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:87:86,1:86:3280:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:87:84,3:84:3214:3:119"
), V19 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:188:185,2:185:6524:2:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:187:183,4:183:6728:4:149", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:186:180,6:180:6764:6:211"
), V20 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:264:259,5:259:9394:5:180", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:276:267,6:267:10068:6:225", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:273:262,5:262:9937:5:189"
), V21 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:210:209,1:209:7464:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:202:200,1:200:7454:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:200:193,5:193:7242:5:202"
), V22 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:179:177,2:177:6481:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:185:183,2:183:6915:2:81", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:184:171,7:171:6570:7:271"
), V23 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:143:140,3:140:5103:3:94", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:148:144,4:144:5477:4:162", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:148:140,3:140:5389:3:119"
), V24 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:116:116,0:116:4172:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:119:113,5:113:4221:5:195", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:119:112,3:112:4197:3:103"
), V25 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:147:147,0:147:5196:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:160:154,5:154:5765:5:195", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:160:150,10:150:5595:10:361"
), V26 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:114:113,1:113:4078:1:27", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:106:105,1:105:3992:1:30", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:106:101,3:101:3900:3:111"
), V27 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:239:237,2:237:8622:2:77", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:236:231,5:231:8803:5:198", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:235:224,7:224:8609:7:273"
), V28 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:172:167,5:167:6139:5:192", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:168:165,3:165:6369:3:118", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:166:160,2:160:6118:2:81"
), V29 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:257:252,5:252:8986:5:191", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:272:267,5:267:10131:5:174", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:272:243,14:243:9285:14:506"
), V30 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:264:256,7:256:9107:7:256", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:279:269,9:269:10163:9:322", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:279:255,6:255:9636:6:231"
), V31 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:76:76,0:76:2653:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:71:69,2:69:2522:2:80", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:70:67,2:67:2503:2:77"
), V32 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:178:178,0:178:6273:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:176:174,2:174:6622:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:176:171,4:171:6484:4:139"
), V33 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:143:140,3:140:5092:3:119", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:135:130,3:130:4881:3:121", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:134:118,10:118:4501:10:359"
), V34 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:192:191,1:191:6905:1:35", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:196:190,3:190:7246:3:85", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:196:186,4:186:7135:4:154"
), V35 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:213:210,3:210:7403:3:115", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:226:220,3:220:8009:3:120", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:226:216,5:216:7949:5:191"
), V36 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:170:168,2:168:5947:2:80", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:165:157,5:157:5839:5:193", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:165:152,4:152:5785:4:130"
), V37 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:204:203,1:203:7752:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:205:191,13:191:7523:13:521", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:203:186,7:186:7371:7:273"
), V38 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:149:147,2:147:5325:2:39", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:138:131,6:131:4989:6:231", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:138:128,3:128:4941:3:109"
), V39 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:492:486,6:486:18307:6:209", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:503:494,7:494:19343:7:280", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:498:475,12:475:18785:12:481"
), V40 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:171:168,3:168:6048:3:113", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:166:160,4:160:6007:4:158", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:164:154,5:154:5840:5:203"
), V41 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:69:68,1:68:2411:1:30", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:71:71,0:71:2650:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:71:63,7:63:2386:7:236"
), V42 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:251:247,4:247:8494:4:142", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:267:259,6:259:9522:6:223", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:267:246,13:246:9251:13:506"
), V43 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:86:86,0:86:3048:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:85:84,1:84:3210:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:82:77,5:77:2900:5:187"
), V44 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:125:124,1:124:4466:1:36", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:124:119,4:119:4429:4:160", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:124:109,8:109:4104:8:304"
), V45 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:86:86,0:86:3045:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:86:85,1:85:3057:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:84:81,1:81:2982:1:41"
), V46 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:241:237,4:237:8307:4:139", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:239:229,10:229:8520:10:375", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:238:227,4:227:8535:4:134"
), V47 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:89:89,0:89:3196:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:83:79,2:79:2952:2:77", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:83:83,0:83:3202:0:0"
), V48 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:104:103,0:103:3798:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:102:101,1:101:3918:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:102:97,4:97:3723:4:143"
), V49 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:157:155,2:155:5630:2:76", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:154:147,4:147:5673:4:162", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:154:148,4:148:5730:4:156"
), V50 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:79:77,2:77:2820:2:73", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:77:71,6:71:2756:6:232", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:77:73,3:73:2826:3:120"
), V51 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:189:185,4:185:6535:4:135", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:201:197,4:197:7319:4:157", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:201:186,9:186:6790:9:333"
), V52 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:250:246,3:246:8679:3:83", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:257:243,13:243:9045:13:494", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:257:251,2:251:9374:2:66"
), V53 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:374:364,9:364:13005:9:350", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:395:381,12:381:14581:12:457", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:394:378,6:378:14429:6:233"
), V54 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:151:149,2:149:5473:2:74", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:149:139,8:139:5221:8:321", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:149:135,7:135:5144:7:269"
), V55 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:93:93,0:93:3481:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:94:94,0:94:3678:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:94:90,2:90:3514:2:81"
), V56 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:202:200,2:200:7369:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:206:202,2:202:7876:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:206:192,10:192:7513:10:396"
), V57 = c("0/0:164:164,0:164:5902:0:0", "0/0:166:162,4:162:6195:4:156", 
"0/0:166:159,4:159:6133:4:144"), V58 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:127:125,2:125:4279:2:79", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:130:124,3:124:4611:3:121", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:129:120,4:120:4466:4:139"
), V59 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:185:184,1:184:6563:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:192:181,10:181:6798:10:390", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:191:186,4:186:7067:4:161"
), V60 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:93:92,1:92:3396:1:37", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:92:90,2:90:3479:2:56", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:92:85,4:85:3282:4:164"
), V61 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:91:91,0:91:3367:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:94:91,2:91:3506:2:61", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:93:80,5:80:3167:5:184"
), V62 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:119:116,3:116:4212:3:116", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:122:120,0:120:4632:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:121:117,2:117:4433:2:44"
), V63 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:173:171,2:171:6295:2:74", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:190:187,3:187:7237:3:123", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:173,8:173:6766:8:300"
), V64 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:199:197,2:197:7156:2:50", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:205:200,3:200:7714:3:115", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:205:191,6:191:7398:6:244"
), V65 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:128:124,3:124:4488:3:108", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:123:119,3:119:4449:3:119", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:122:113,6:113:4245:6:229"
), V66 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:99:96,3:96:3514:3:114", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:99:95,4:95:3642:4:157", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:99:96,0:96:3692:0:0"
), V67 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:178:177,0:177:6244:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:179,8:179:6732:8:317", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:188:170,8:170:6453:8:296"
), V68 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:203:203,0:203:7094:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:206:200,6:200:7409:6:208", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:206:192,4:192:7161:4:147"
), V69 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:149:145,4:145:5284:4:148", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:145:142,3:142:5450:3:120", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:145:135,7:135:5138:7:273"
), V70 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:57:57,0:57:2014:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:58:54,3:54:2042:3:123", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:58:55,2:55:2094:2:78"
), V71 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:209:207,2:207:7422:2:51", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:219:216,3:216:8106:3:117", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:216:205,6:205:7754:6:220"
), V72 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:132:131,1:131:4533:1:29", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:136:133,2:133:4994:2:72", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:136:126,9:126:4707:9:307"
), V73 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:156:155,1:155:5756:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:160:155,3:155:5859:3:123", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:160:150,6:150:5828:6:172"
), V74 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:146:144,2:144:5269:2:55", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:150:149,1:149:5680:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:150:139,9:139:5320:9:348"
), V75 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:283:280,3:280:9926:3:106", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:301:294,5:294:10911:5:186", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:301:275,15:275:10428:15:538"
), V76 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:278:273,5:273:9615:5:199", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:281:274,6:274:10163:6:237", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:281:269,9:269:10045:9:361"
), V77 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:148:145,3:145:5187:3:102", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:148:139,8:139:5109:8:316", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:147:135,5:135:5000:5:171"
), V78 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:98:96,2:96:3520:2:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:100:95,3:95:3539:3:108", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:98:93,3:93:3543:3:109"
), V79 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:161:161,0:161:5991:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:156:152,2:152:5819:2:82", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:155:151,2:151:5836:2:75"
), V80 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:294:289,4:289:10251:4:148", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:328:316,9:316:11851:9:332", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:328:311,8:311:11736:8:300"
), V81 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:89:84,5:84:2999:5:170", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:79:76,2:76:2899:2:72", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:78:71,2:71:2640:2:81"
), V82 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:256:252,4:252:8725:4:118", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:279:271,4:271:10063:4:152", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:279:258,14:258:9564:14:549"
), V83 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:131:130,1:130:4710:1:26", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:132:131,1:131:4879:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:127:118,7:118:4401:7:279"
), V84 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:248:246,2:246:8736:2:68", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:263:256,5:256:9603:5:200", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:264:249,11:249:9500:11:411"
), V85 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:150:148,1:148:5295:1:27", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:156:151,4:151:5718:4:158", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:156:143,8:143:5426:8:274"
), V86 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:161:160,1:160:5862:1:39", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:166:160,6:160:6085:6:206", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:165:151,9:151:5764:9:353"
), V87 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:126:125,1:125:4304:1:38", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:125:124,1:124:4598:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:124:118,4:118:4391:4:123"
), V88 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:82:81,1:81:2959:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:83:80,3:80:3018:3:111", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:83:82,1:82:3082:1:41"
), V89 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:180:179,0:179:6457:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:179:176,1:176:6760:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:174:166,8:166:6457:8:290"
), V90 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:165:165,0:165:5836:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:163:159,3:159:5920:3:117", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:161:155,5:155:5759:5:178"
), V91 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:60:59,1:59:2160:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:58:57,1:57:2151:1:39", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:58:52,1:52:1998:1:38"
), V92 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:218:213,4:213:7717:4:141", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:223:220,2:220:8249:2:64", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:222:204,12:204:7672:12:447"
), V93 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:197:193,4:193:6975:4:113", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:202:194,7:194:7337:7:278", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:202:191,4:191:7285:4:149"
), V94 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:220:219,1:219:7697:1:39", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:233:226,6:226:8502:6:222", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:231:218,7:218:8277:7:265"
), V95 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:161:160,1:160:5680:1:24", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:155:149,6:149:5460:6:229", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:153:142,8:142:5197:8:305"
), V96 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:276:275,1:275:9672:1:40", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:301:298,3:298:11221:3:112", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:301:285,8:285:10958:8:296"
), V97 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:117:115,2:115:4210:2:78", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:121:117,3:117:4474:3:118", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:121:117,3:117:4479:3:123"
), V98 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:227:226,1:226:8173:1:37", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:246:239,5:239:9069:5:198", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:246:222,12:222:8464:12:463"
), V99 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:214:212,2:212:7590:2:49", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:208:203,4:203:7672:4:124", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:206:188,7:188:7096:7:273"
), V100 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:212:208,4:208:7450:4:156", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:217:206,8:206:7743:8:323", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:215:195,13:195:7406:13:464"
), V101 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:270:268,2:268:9500:2:55", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:278:272,3:272:10136:3:80", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:278:256,13:256:9662:13:506"
), V102 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:176:174,2:174:6232:2:78", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:164:162,1:162:6019:1:41", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:159:153,4:153:5690:4:147"
), V103 = c("0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0:213:213,0:213:7408:0:0", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1:220:210,10:210:7965:10:379", 
"0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/1:219:203,13:203:7765:13:490"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```